# java.lang.Process.waitFor() is hanging

Tags: java

I am trying to execute below command on Solaris which is hanging.

> swmml -l /tmp/swmmlLog.txt -n N1 -e DISPLAY-M3UA-LSET;
>
> ;swmml -> perl script.

I tried to flush out the streams/closing the streams. Nothing is working. I tried with both `ProcessBBuilder` and `Runtime.exec()` but of no success.

We tried to read from the streams.But the read method is itself hanging.
The following code is not printing anything.

```
 while (true) {
     String s = br.readLine ();
     if (s == null) break;
     System.out.println (s);
 }
```

Comment: post the non-functional code, and remember to format it properly.

Answer (score 8):

You say that you are flushing and closing the streams, but are you fully *reading* the content of both standard out and standard error?

A common problem is that the child process blocks because its standard error pipe fills up when the parent Java process neglects to consume its output.